# Call a Python script from a different Python script located at a different location

Tags: python

I have a Python script which is calling a class of another Python script. 
The structure of these two scripts are as follows:

```
c:\testing\sample.py
c:\testing\example\demo\projects\module.py
```

Now inside `sample.py` I am calling `module.py` as follows:

```
from "c:/testing/example/demo/projects/module.py" import module_C
```

When I execute this portion of `sample.py` I get an error `There is an error in program` and this error occurs in its first line only.

How shall I call the `module_C` inside `sample.py`?

Answer (score 0):

the `from/import` syntax does not work with files, only with modules.

To achieve what you want, there are 2 possibilities

**first one: turn traversing directories into modules:**

- create empty `__init__.py` files in `c:/testing/example/demo`, and `c:/testing/example/demo/projects`,
- then `from demo.projects.module import module_C`

**second one: add path dynamically:**

```
import sys,os
sys.path.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"demo/projects"))
from module import module_C
```

knowing where you are running, use current module directory and add the `demo/projects` absolute path: it works because the paths have a common prefix)